# PHP doesn't execute function

Tags: php, function

SOLVED: Read the comments below @Eray.

I have a PHP function to look through text and convert text emoticons to images. :), :(, :|, etc. I also have a function that looks through text and replaces BBCode with HTML. I execute these on a string from a database. Both of these use the global variable $newtext.

```
emoticon($row['words']);
bb($row['words']);
echo "<b>" . $row['username'] . "</b> - " . $row['time'];
echo "<p>" . $newtext . "</p>";
echo "";
```

The odd thing about this, is that now (I can't remember what I did) the emoticon function doesn't work, but the bb function does. By doesn't work, I mean doesn't replace anything. Text remains text. This had worked before. Also, every few times, $newtext comes before the username. Here are my functions...

```
function emoticon($text)
{
global $newtext;
$newtext=str_replace(":)", "<img src='emoticons/smile.gif'>", $text);
$newtext=str_replace(":(", "<img src='emoticons/sad.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace(":D", "<img src='emoticons/biggrin.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace(":p", "<img src='emoticons/tongue.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace(":P", "<img src='emoticons/tongue.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace(":|", "<img src='emoticons/neutral.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace("8)", "<img src='emoticons/cool.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace("8D", "<img src='emoticons/cool.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace(":o", "<img src='emoticons/surprised.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace(":O", "<img src='emoticons/surprised.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace(";)", "<img src='emoticons/wink.gif'>", $newtext);
$newtext=str_replace("^<**>^", "<img src='emoticons/crab.gif'>", $newtext);
}

function bb($text) 
{
global $newtext;
$array=array(

"[b]" => "<b>",
"[/b]" => "</b>",

"[i]" => "<i>",
"[/i]" => "</i>",

"[u]" => "<u>",
"[/u]" => "</u>",

"[big]" => "<h1>",
"[/big]" => "</h1>",

);
$newtext = str_ireplace(array_keys($array), array_values($array), $text);
}
```

Could you explain or help me? Also, is there a better way than using global variables? I know they can be a bit "dangerous."

Comment: without providing your functions that's quite hard. using global $variables is generally a bad idea, you should avoid that.

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not provide us any meaningful information. Since we aren't psychics, you need to tell us what the emoticon() function is, what error do you get when your code executes, what strings do you test your function with, etc.

Comment: +1 for @zaphod1984 's comment. You can `return` it, instead of using global variables, for example. We will help you, if you share your functions. `emoticon() and bb()`

Comment: `$row['words']` returning an array ? YOur emoticon() won't work with arrays.

Comment: @Eray I can't think why it would. It's just some text that was entered in previously on my site. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function emoticon($text)
{
$smiley = array(
    ':)',
    ':(',
);

$replace = array(
    "<img src='emoticons/smile.gif'>",
    "<img src='emoticons/sad.gif'>",
);

     return str_replace($smiley, $replace, $text);
}
```

Comment: Gives me a "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in myfile.php on line 142"

Comment: therefore , `$text` isn't an array. Just a minute i'll write a working function for you.

Comment: :( Did that and it didn't work. I know the function works, because if I do echo emoticon('hi :)') it works. I still can't think what could cause this.

Comment: @CoffeeRain , can you print contents of `$row['words']` ? Put this top of your functions : `echo $row['words'];`

Comment: Here is one of them... thecreator - Tue, 24 Jan 2012 13:14:59 -0500 Yeah... :(

Comment: @CoffeeRain , Here it's working : http://codepad.viper-7.com/h0PO7I BUt you said, it's not working if we work with global variables. It's working : http://codepad.viper-7.com/S1eemK (DOn't forget, **i'm not recommending to using global variables**, use first one.)

Comment: Yes, calling the function like that works. Calling it for $row['words'] doesn't.

Comment: @CoffeeRain , can you share try them just before `emoticon($row['words']);
` . Try this `print_r($row['words']);` and `echo $row['words'];` ANd tell me what is printing to screen .

Comment: Thanks for being helpful!! I figured it out. I was calling bb on $row['words'] not on $newtext. :D That just printed out the bb not emoticon or both. Thanks again!

Comment: @CoffeeRain so you can give me +1 :D

Comment: No, I don't have enough reputation to do that, and it doesn't help that I just got voted down quite a few points when I was close to being able to. :( I would though.

Comment: so now you want +1 from me :D

Comment: I will, you got negative votes because your question was really bad formatted, and doesn't explaining problem. But now it's pretty good. Also, You have to accept an answer if you want to increase your rate.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't want people to get confused and think the actual answer was right and not the comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better do this:

```
$text = $row['words'];
$text = emoticon($text);
$text = bb($text);
echo "<b>" . $row['username'] . "</b> - " . $row['time'];
echo "<p>" . $text . "</p>";
echo "";
```

And then edit your functions like this:

```
function emoticon($text)
{
    // remove this line: global $newtext;
    $text=str_replace(":)", "<img src='emoticons/smile.gif'>", $text);
    // etc...
    $text=str_replace("^<**>^", "<img src='emoticons/crab.gif'>", $text);

    return $text;
}

function bb($text) 
{
    // remove this line: global $newtext;
    $array=array(
    // etc...
    );
    return str_ireplace(array_keys($array), array_values($array), $text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First, DEFINE your PHP functions:**

```
function emoticon ( $string )
{
    $emoticons = array( ':)' , ';)' );
    $icons = ('happy.gif','wink.gif');
    return str_replace( $emoticons, $icons , $string );
}

function bb( $string )
{
    //BOLD [b]text[/b]
    $string = preg_replace('/(\[b\]([\w\d\s\.]+)\[\/b\])/i','<b>$2</b>',$string);

    //ITALIC [i]text[/i]
    $string = preg_replace('/(\[i\]([\w\d\s\.]+)\[\/i\])/i','<em>$2</em>',$string);

    //UNDERLINE [u]text[/u]
    $string = preg_replace('/(\[u\]([\w\d\s\.]+)\[\/u\])/i','<u>$2</u>',$string);

    return $string;
}
```

**Second, Call you PHP defined functions:**

```
echo bb( "[b]Bold[/b]" ); //Return <b>Bold</b>
```

> **Bold**

```
echo bb( "[i]Italic[/i]" ); //Return <em>Italic</em>
```

> *Bold*

```
echo bb( "[i]My [b]Text[/b][/i]" ); //Return <em>My <b>Text</b></em>
```

> *My **Text***

```
$var = $_POST['foo'];

echo bb( $var );
```

**Third, Test your code:**

```
emoticon($row['words']);
bb($row['words']);
echo "<b>" . $row['username'] . "</b> - " . $row['time'];
echo "<p>" . $newtext . "</p>";
echo "";
```

Comment: OK, I got tried echo emoticon("hello :)") and it worked. It didn't work for the last part though.

Answer (score -1):

didnt test it but this should do:

notice that instead of using `global $newtext` i'm creating a local variable and return it to the outer scope via `return`.

```
function emoticon($text) {
    $newtext=str_replace(":)", "<img src='emoticons/smile.gif'>", $text);
    $newtext=str_replace(":(", "<img src='emoticons/sad.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace(":D", "<img src='emoticons/biggrin.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace(":p", "<img src='emoticons/tongue.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace(":P", "<img src='emoticons/tongue.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace(":|", "<img src='emoticons/neutral.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace("8)", "<img src='emoticons/cool.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace("8D", "<img src='emoticons/cool.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace(":o", "<img src='emoticons/surprised.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace(":O", "<img src='emoticons/surprised.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace(";)", "<img src='emoticons/wink.gif'>", $newtext);
    $newtext=str_replace("^<**>^", "<img src='emoticons/crab.gif'>", $newtext);

    return $newtext;
}

function bb($text) {
    $array=array(
        "[b]" => "<b>",
        "[/b]" => "</b>",

        "[i]" => "<i>",
        "[/i]" => "</i>",

        "[u]" => "<u>",
        "[/u]" => "</u>",

        "[big]" => "<h1>",
        "[/big]" => "</h1>",
    );

    return str_ireplace(array_keys($array), array_values($array), $text);
}

$row['words'] = emoticon( $row['words'] );

$row['words'] = bb( $row['words'] );
```